# How to determine the sum of the series $\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{2^n}$

Tags: analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

> I have to determine the sum of the series  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{2^n}$$

*My Attempt*: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac12}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=2+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$$.
 So,I am stuck on determining the value of $\,\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Wow, even Wolfram|Alpha can't show steps for this one.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: While you're at it, you could try to find the sum of $\sum (n+1)x^n$ for $|x|<1$. Hint: it is a derivative.

Comment: $
\begin{array}{l}if:x = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)^n }  + \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty } {n\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)^n }  = \frac{1}{{1 - \frac{1}{2}}} + \frac{{\frac{1}{2}}}{{\left( {1 - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2 }} = 2 + 2 = 4 \\ 
 \end{array}
$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1_{(k \leq n)}}{2^n}$$
$$=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{2^k}}{1-.5}$$
$$ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$
$$= 2$$

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: The best answers contain no words!

Comment: @Gautam  I am confused about the line $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^n}$$?  The line does not contain $k$ whereas it says $k$ runs from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n$. I substituted for n with this.

Comment: @GautamShenoy thanks a lot.Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Denote $S=\sum_{n=0}\frac{n}{2^n}$. What would it be $2S-S$?

Comment: Very good observation. Essentially, you get my last step in 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

Take the geometric series $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}$. Look at its derivative and plug in $x=1/2$. Of course you need to justify that everything works, but that's standard.